# Adding text to a column based on the row name in R

Tags: r

I am a new user of R. I have written an `if` function which gives me rows of my data that have lengths outside of a set length range. The output is presented like this:

```
1690 Field mouse 100
```

(rowname, species, length)

I have a quality column (`df$Quality`) that I would like to add notes for all those outside of the range. Is it possible to write some code which is based on the row name i.e. at this row in the `df$Quality` column add this text `"Query: size above range"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this example can help:

```
> df <- data.frame(Rowname=1:6, Species=letters[1:6],length=rep(c(99,101),times=3))
> df
  Rowname Species length
1       1       a     99
2       2       b    101
3       3       c     99
4       4       d    101
5       5       e     99
6       6       f    101
> df[df$length > 100,"Quality"] <- "Query: size above range"
> df
  Rowname Species length                 Quality
1       1       a     99                    <NA>
2       2       b    101 Query: size above range
3       3       c     99                    <NA>
4       4       d    101 Query: size above range
5       5       e     99                    <NA>
6       6       f    101 Query: size above range
```

As an alternative starting point, you can also use the row.names(df) to do similar processing.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, especially if your have a large data set, is to use the `dplyr` pacakge:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  mutate(Quality=ifelse(mpg>20, "Query: size above range", "Query: size below range"))

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb                 Quality
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 Query: size above range
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 Query: size above range
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 Query: size above range
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 Query: size above range
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Query: size below range
...
```